# InfoVis Treemap dynamic data from another file

Tags: json, treemap

I have code from example 1.js (link give below)
here that variable json contains json data,instead of specify this data in this file i want to refer from another file which will help me making the protovis treemap dynamic.

I am new to json i don't know how to refer store json data from another file into a variable
full code is available in this link http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.js

```
 function init(){
 //init data
  var json = {
 "children": [
 {
   "children": [
     {
       "children": [], 
       "data": {
         "playcount": "276", 
         "$color": "#8E7032", 
         "image": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/11403219.jpg", 
         "$area": 276
       }, 
       "id": "album-Thirteenth Step", 
       "name": "Thirteenth Step"
     }, 
     {
       "children": [], 
       "data": {
         "playcount": "271", 
         "$color": "#906E32", 
         "image": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/11393921.jpg", 
         "$area": 271
       }, 
       "id": "album-Mer De Noms", 
       "name": "Mer De Noms"
     }
   ], 
   "data": {
     "playcount": 547, 
     "$area": 547
   }, 
   "id": "artist_A Perfect Circle", 
   "name": "A Perfect Circle"
 }, 
 {
   "children": [
     {
       "children": [], 
       "data": {
         "playcount": "209", 
         "$color": "#AA5532", 
         "image": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/32349839.jpg", 
         "$area": 209
       }, 
       "id": "album-Above", 
       "name": "Above"
     }
   ], 
   "data": {
     "playcount": 209, 
     "$area": 209
   }, 
   "id": "artist_Mad Season", 
   "name": "Mad Season"
 }
  ......
```